# How to install record my desktop-0.3.8.1?

Tags: recordmydesktop

I am trying to install recordmydesktop-0.3.8.1 using the install file given in the folder but the all the commands give an error. This file was originally a tar.gz.

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details; plus what commands you've tried (*following the instructions from download site you used*) and what error message(s) you received.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid inflicting yourself any trouble with the risk of damaging your system, instead install `recordmydesktop` from the Ubuntu software center, or using a command `sudo apt install recordmydesktop`. On the latest Long Term Release Ubuntu version 22.04, this will give you version 0.4.0.1.

For 22.04 users, note that the default session in 22.04 is Ubuntu running on Wayland. As a screen recording software,`recordmydesktop` may not work on Wayland, so you will need to switch to the session "Ubuntu on Xorg".